# You can use CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting for AppSettings, what is the equivalent approach for Connection Strings

Tags: azure, configuration, connection-string

Using CloudConfigurationManager, you can access AppSettings in your application or if running in the context of Azure the portal settings instead if the values exist there.
But I've not seen the way to get to the ConnectionStrings section of the configuration file or even the portal settings.
What objects should I be looking for?

Comment: Are you looking for `ConnectionStrings` kind of element in Cloud Configuration file (*.cscfg)?

Comment: Nope, not that. I'm looking for an object model, similar to CloudConfigurationManager that will give me access to Connection Strings in a .config file, or the Connection Strings section of the azure config, if running in that context.

Answer (score 3):

> Note that in order to use CloudConfigurationManager to read from an app.config file, you must specify the configuration settings in the appSettings tag...
>   Only configuration settings within the appSettings tag can be read by CloudConfigurationManager.

[Per this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.aspx)

Comment: Yes, that's clear @Nathan, I wanted to know specifically if there was some other way to interact with the configuration settings in the connectionStrings tag.

Comment: I think your options are to move your connection strings into app settings as shown in that article, or to not use CloudConfigurationManager. That would mean giving up the abstraction layer that allows you to not need to know what environment you are in (web.config, app.config, .cscfg). If that is acceptable then you can just use something like: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconstname"].ConnectionString

Answer (score 3):

I just came across the [AmbientConnectionStringProvider](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/AmbientConnectionStringProvider.cs) in one of MSFT's github accounts.  Which in turn is using a [ConfigurationUtility class](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/f958e470712f2bbeb65c8546ad3698e4064f2ee9/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/ConfigurationUtility.cs).
ConfigurationUtility is then doing this:

```
public static string GetConnectionFromConfigOrEnvironment(string connectionName)
{
    string configValue = null;
    var connectionStringEntry = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName];
    if (connectionStringEntry != null)
    {
        configValue = connectionStringEntry.ConnectionString;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configValue))
    {
        // config values take precedence over environment values
        return configValue;
    }

    return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(connectionName) ?? configValue;
}
```

This approach may be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I can use regular ol' ConfigurationManager for both my AppSettings as well as ConnectionStrings.
It's smart enough to know when I'm running in Azure and when I'm running locally.

More details available here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/